# Can anyone file a case against us because of our negative review?

Tags: liability, india

I am living in India. I gave a Google review on a bike shop. Since I was not happy with their interactions, I wrote a negative review. Later I talked with an executive, he was nice, and I promised him that I will edit my review, but I forgot to do so, now he just called me and said he is going to file a case. Is it possible?

Comment: [You can always be sued in civil court](http://meta.law.stackexchange.com/q/224/10).  Do you have a more particular on-topic question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, someone can take action if you have defamed them, which [this](http://indianexpress.com/article/explained/simply-put-the-what-why-of-defamation/) article summaries for India. Assuming you are being threatened with *civil* rather than *criminal* defamation:

> Here, defamation can take two forms – libel (by writings) and slander (by spoken words). In order to establish that a particular statement – written or spoken – is defamatory, it must be proved that it is false, defamatory and published and lowered the reputation of a specific person or an identifiable set of people in the eyes of the general public.

The best defence against a defamation suit is to show that everything you said is 100% true. So, if you confined your criticism to factual statements and how you felt about them you should be OK in court.

Notwithstanding, defending yourself is expensive in time and money so if you can settle the dispute by negotiation so much the better.